# git subtree: add different branches from a project at different prefixes

Tags: git-subtree

I have a *module* repository with some branches *branchA*, *branchB* etc. I would like to import these branches into a *project* repository using git subtree. I set up my *project* repository like this:

```
git remote add module /path/to/module.git
git fetch module
git subtree add -P folderA module/branchA
git subtree add -P folderB module/branchB
```

This seems to work as expected, and I've got files and history from the correct branches in *folderA* and *folderB*.

Now I have changes in the *master* branch of *module*, which I apply to both *branchA* and *branchB* (by rebasing *branchA* and *branchB*) and want to update *project*.

```
git fetch module
```

fetches these changes into *project*. However, when I then do

```
git subtree pull -P folderA module branchA
git subtree pull -P folderB module branchB
```

only *folderA* gets updated. For *folderB*, I get the following message:

```
From /path/to/module.git
 * branch            branchB -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

and the changes are not merged. Apparently, git is not correctly taking into account that the changes had been applied to path *folderA*, but not *folderB*. Does anyone have an idea what I could do to make this scenario work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reply to myself:

It seems the solution was buried somewhere in the documentation of the original contribution to git-subtree at [github repository for git-subtree (outdated)](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt). There, it reads

> ### OPTIONS FOR add, merge, push, pull
>
> --squash::
>
> This option is only valid for add, merge, push and pull
>   commands.
>
> ...
>
> Using '--squash' also helps avoid problems when the same
>   subproject is included multiple times in the same
>   project, or is removed and then re-added. In such a
>   case, it doesn't make sense to combine the histories
>   anyway, since it's unclear which part of the history
>   belongs to which subtree.

Adding `--squash` to the `git subtree` commands pulls in the correct history into the right places.